# How to clean up the mesh in Open3D?

Tags: python, mesh, surface, open3d

I created surface mesh from 3D cloud points using Open3D library in python. I have a lot of cases where the domains are similar to each other. **For most of the cases, the open3D does a fine job in creating a closed surface mesh, but for few cases it creates some outlier meshes from the domain.**
Below is the code for surface mesh from Open3D.

```
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud('./mesh.xyz')
pcd.estimate_normals()

# to obtain a consistent normal orientation
pcd.orient_normals_towards_camera_location(pcd.get_center())
pcd.normals = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector( - np.asarray(pcd.normals))

# surface reconstruction using Poisson reconstruction
mesh, _ = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_poisson(pcd, depth=9)

o3d.io.write_triangle_mesh('mesh.stl', mesh)
```

**I have attached pics of the outlier mesh obtained from the domain. How to clean those mesh from Open3D?**. This occurs for only few of the test cases. We can easily see in the outlier image how the mesh is outside the domain.

[image: Complete mesh after completion]

[image: Outlier when the mesh is zoomed in]

Any leads will be appreciated.

Regards,
Sunag R A.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Open3D Connected-components to remove outliers.
Example link -
http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/geometry/mesh.html#Connected-components

Note - Please remove the duplicate vertices from mesh before using Connected-components.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).